# Scala case class construction using JObject

Tags: scala, serialization

I'm following an example on https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/tests/src/test/scala/org/json4s/native/SerializationExamples.scala to construct a Custom Serializer.  If anyone has any experience with Custom Serializers in scala, your input would be greatly appreciated!!  I'm getting this error:

```
value JObject is not a case class constructor, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq
```

method

For this bit of code:

```
case JObject(JField("username", JString(s)) :: JField("email", Jstring(e)) :: Nil) => new NewUser(s, e, null, null)
```

Has anyone encountered a problem similar to this before? Is anyone aware of how this case constructor process works?

Edit:

Here is the whole code for my class:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.scalatra.json._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

case class NewUser(
    username: String, 
    email: String, 
    password: String, 
    confirm_password: String
)

object DataStore {
  val users = List(
      NewUser("yacomink", "yacomink.anteateaaaaar@yahoo.com", "aol123", "aol123"),
      NewUser("LadyAva", "lady_ava@excite.com", "aol456", "aol456"),
      NewUser("MoeLarryAndJesus", "moelarryandjesus@aol.com", "aol789", "aol789")
      )
}

object CustomSerialization extends Specification{
  import native.Serialization
  import native.Serialization.{read, write => swrite}
  import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
  import java.util.regex.Pattern
  import org.json4s.CustomSerializer

  class UserSerializer extends CustomSerializer[NewUser](format => (
      {
        case JObject(JField("username", JString(s)) :: JField("email", Jstring(e)) :: Nil) => new NewUser(s, e, null, null)
      },
      {
        case x: NewUser => JObject(JField("username", JString(x.username)) ::JField("email", JString(x.email)) :: Nil)
      }
      ))

  implicit val formats = native.Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new UserSerializer   

  val i = new NewUser("Larry", "lmack@gmail.com", "lol123", "lol123")
  val ser = swrite(i)

  println(ser)
      }
```

Comment: Can you include the full code for your custom serializer as opposed to just that snippet?  I'm looking at the code in org.json4s.JsonAST.scala and JObject is clearly a case class.  Are you importing org.json4s.JsonAST._?

Comment: Why are you importing `import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST`?  Shouldn't that import instead be `import org.json4s.JsonAST._`?

Comment: Right, I changed that in Eclipse; Eclipse is still throwing that "not a case constructor" flag

Comment: Is it possible to create a CustomSerializer without using case constructors?

Comment: You didn't make the exact change I suggested.  I'm suggesting that the import for `JsonAST` comes from `org.json4s` and not directly from `net.liftweb.json`.  Can you try making that change?

Comment: so sorry! Read your last comment too quickly!! 
Which org.json4s .jar file are you pulling JsonAST from? I have Json4s-native and Json4s-core installed in my directory, and neither contain the JsonAST class

Comment: in other words, `import org.json4s.JsonAST._` throws an "object JsonAST is not a member of package org.json4s" with my current reference-library setup, which contains Json4s-native, Json4s-core, paranamer and lift-json-2.0